# Circular array and elimination in C, how to return the last "living" element index?

Tags: arrays, c, function, circular-reference, josephus

I am trying to write a code that will simulate a `circle` of a fixed size of people that have one sword. The closest "living person" to the current `index` will be eliminated and the sword will be passed to the next living person (after the one who got killed) and so on.

I want it to be written without linked lists.

**Example:**
A group of 3 people:
`arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = 1, arr[2] = 1`

**First turn:**

- `arr[0] KILLS arr[1] and the sword gets PASSED to arr[2]`

**Values of elements after the first turn:**

`arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = 0, arr[2] = 1`

**Second turn:**

- `arr[2] KILLS arr[0] and stays the last player`

**Values of elements after the second turn:**

`arr[0] = 0, arr[1] = 0, arr[2] = 1`

- `arr[2]'s index gets returned by the main function`.

What I thought about was:

- array
- set the values all of elements to `1`
- circulate and check each time `if (1 == arr[i])`
- set a flag to determine whether to kill or just pass the sword to this guy.
- return the current index that indicates that's the index of the last player alive.

For example, lets say we have 5 people in our group:
`[1] [1] [1] [1] [1]`

**First round**:

`give_sword = 0`

`i = 0` does not enter the first `if` because `give_sword` is not `1`.
It enters the second `if`, and finds the closest living person using the function `findClosestLivingPerson` and gets his index and sets his value to `0` (== kills the closest living person).
It sets `give_sword` to `1`.

Decreases the `players_counter` and checks if there is only one player left. If not, continues the loop.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findClosestLivingPerson(int arr[], int index, int group_size);


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    int group_size = 0, players_counter = 0;
    int i = 0, give_sword = 0;
    int arr[100] = {0};
    
    printf("Enter group size: \n");
    scanf("%d",&group_size);
    
    for (i = 0; i < group_size; i++)
    {
         arr[i] = 1;
    }
   
    players_counter = group_size;
    
        for (i = 0; i < group_size; (i+1) % group_size)
        {
            if (1 == arr[i])
            {
                if(1 == give_sword) /* should give sword, not to kill */
                {
                    give_sword = 0;
                }
                else /* should be killed */
                {
                    arr[findClosestLivingPerson(arr,i, group_size)] = 0;
                    give_sword = 1;
                    --players_counter;
                    if (players_counter == 1)
                    { 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    printf("Winner is %d ",i);
    return 0;
}

int findClosestLivingPerson(int arr[], int index, int group_size)
{
    for (; index < group_size; (index+1) % group_size)
    {
        if (arr[index] == 1)
        return index;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says:

> In function ‘main’: last_man.c:23:43: warning: statement with no
> effect [-Wunused-value]    23 |         for (i = 0; i < group_size;
> (i+1) % group_size)
>
> last_man.c: In function ‘findClosestLivingPerson’: last_man.c:49:42:
> warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]    49 |     for (;
> index < group_size; (index+1) % group_size)

The `(index+1) % group_size` is meant to circulate through this array.

Comment: In the future, prepare an [mre] to post with your question. That means **complete** source code that can be compiled to produce the error messages shown. Your error message indicates line 23, but the problem is on line 2, so we know you omitted some of the code. You should omit code—you should reduce the total code of your program to just the code necessary to reproduce the problem. Take out all the unrelated functions, leave `#include` statements that are necessary (but take out unnecessary ones), and then compile the reduced code and post the messages from that, so the line numbers match.

Comment: Re the last paragraph: Stack Overflow is for specific questions, not tips and suggestions and not for multiple diverse questions per post.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes sorry about that, I just added the full code. My main purpose here is to find my mistakes on why it returns the wrong value.

Comment: @NoobCoder A big mistake was found in code and provided in an answer.  Changing your code after a good answer invites down-votes.  Recommend reverting your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler says, `(i+1) % group_size` has no effect. It computes the remainder of the sum of `i` and one. After that, it does nothing with the result.

The third part of a `for` statement is just an expression that is evaluated. It does not automatically update the loop index or do anything else. If you want it to update `i`, you must write an assignment, like `i = (i+1) % group_size`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood how `for` loop works .

Format should be like this:

```
for( initialization, condition, iteration )
```

example:

```
for( int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1 )
```

`(i + 1) % group_size` isn't an iteration( it isn't assigning the result to i ) , what you really want to do is

```
i = ( i + 1 ) % group_size;
```

Same applies for the second warning .

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't the major reason though that I have opened this question. I just fixed and added the full code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. Let's do this in a way that results in nice code.

```
struct actor {
    int label;
    struct actor *next;
};
```

With this struct we can make a nice linked list and loop it back around:

```
int n = 5;
int i;

struct actor *actors = calloc(n, sizeof *actors);
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    actors[i].label = i;
    actors[i].next = &actors[i+1];
}
actors[i].label = i;
actors[i].next = &actors[0];
```

Ok, now we can assign the first killer:

```
struct actor *k = actors;
```

We also need a kill function:

```
struct actor *kill(struct actor *a)
{
    if (a->next != a) {
        printf("%d kills %d\n", a->label, a->next->label);
        a->next = a->next->next;
    } else {
        printf("%d is last man standing\n", a->label);
        a->next = NULL;
    }
    return a->next;
}
```

What this does: it removes the next person from the circular linked list (as that is the one that is killed). The lookup time for the next person is always the same.

And with everything in place, we can start the spree:

```
while (k) {
    k = kill(k);
}
```

This is not perfect code by any means, but it is a nice example of how you can make the algorithm incredibly simple if you put a little effort in setting up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort but I don't know linked lists yet and I need it to be written in the old fashioned "ugly" way (loops, many functions..)

Comment: I don't know why but it gives me the wrong value and output (my code). For 100 people, it gives me `7` as the output. while it should be 73.